# How can I make a class that inherits methods from another class in python but also change only some part of a certain method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance

example:
I have a class that is called "MicroSDCard" this class inherits from a class that is called "MemoryCard", but there is one change between them. MicroSDCard can get another value that is called Frequency, and should retrurn it using the **init** method like this "self.max_freq". How can I make it happen?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the 'super' function ?

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
class MemoryCard(object):
    def __init__(self, size):
        print ('MemoryCard size is ', size)

class MicroSDCard(MemoryCard):
    def __init__(self, max_freq, *args, **kw):
        MemoryCard.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.max_freq = max_freq


print ("MicroSDCard max_freq is ", MicroSDCard(5, size=3).max_freq)
```

Comment: Thanks alot Yoav! but can you explain me the meaning of " *args, **kw " how does this conect to the memorycard?

Comment: @Gal Cesana This is called parameter packing/unpacking. please see http://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments

Comment: @Gal Cesana Sababa, Please up-vote/accept the answer,,,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand you correctly, but I would do the following:

1. re-write the `__init__` method in `MicroSDCard` class with the new attribute.
2. for any method that utilize this new attribute, you need to re-write (overload) it in the `MicroSDCard` class definition.

That looks too simple, so I guess I didn't get your question :)